# log4net 1 appender 2 files

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

Is there a possibility to have one appender for **log4net** that would log information to two files if it meets treshold level. It it is INFO level it will write everything besides debug if it is debug, it writes everything including debug and just keep those two. I could do it with two appenders, however I want to have only one variable that would figure out based on treshold level to which log file write, to only one, or to both.

```html
 <appender name="Name" 
      type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
      <file value="Path" />
      <treshold value="info" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="2000KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <Header value="[Start]&#13;&#10;" />
        <Footer value="[End]&#13;&#10;" />
        <ConversionPattern value="%-5level %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
```

Comment: As you mention, people typically do this with two appenders, each with its own filename and threshold level. If your situation restricts you to just one appender for some reason, then one approach is to write your own appender class. Derive from AppenderSkeleton, and have your class hold two instances of RollingFileAppender. Override the Append() method to pass the event to the appropriate appender.

Comment: The reason why I couldn't go with two appenders was, that in that case I would have to write two log.Foo() statements in every place If I would want to log something in to the files. Why? Because our situation requires us to have two separate log files. One for developers and another one for IT Support team. Therefore I chose to go with Nlog. I should probably close this question?

Comment: you can have a single log.Foo() appear in any number of appenders. We have the same type of setup at my firm, one log file for less-technical support people and a second for techy's. I can post an example as an answer if it would help, just let me know.

Comment: Yes, that would definitely help me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure log4net to have individual log messages write to two (or more) different files. You can even have each file use a different threshold value.

Here is an example with two log files, one called basic.log that includes INFO or higher messages, and one called details.log that includes DEBUG or higher messages. The sample shows that a log.Debug() call will have its output go to just the details.log file, and a log.Info() call will have its output in both files.

Here is the main program:

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        log.Debug("This is a debug message");
        log.Info("This is an info message");
    }
}
```

And the app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" />
  </startup>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="BasicFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, log4net">
      <file value="C:\temp\basic.log"/>
      <threshold value="INFO"/>
      <appendToFile value="True"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <Header value="[Start]&#13;&#10;" />
        <Footer value="[End]&#13;&#10;" />
        <ConversionPattern value="%-5level %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="DetailsFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, log4net">
      <file value="C:\temp\details.log"/>
      <threshold value="DEBUG"/>
      <appendToFile value="True"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <Header value="[Start]&#13;&#10;" />
        <Footer value="[End]&#13;&#10;" />
        <ConversionPattern value="%-5level %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="BasicFile"/>
      <appender-ref ref="DetailsFile"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

When I run this, c:\temp\basic.log has just the INFO message, and c:\temp\details.log has both messages.

Comment: Okay, so you initialize log4net variable by class type, that was probably my issue, I  thought the only possible way was to get them by appender name. Thank you!